# Lie-Gap for Gap-Toothed

Tags: etymology

While reading *Go Tell It On the Mountain*, I came across the hyphenated word "lie-gap." The phrase from the sentence reads, "She had the lie-gap between her teeth" (The Dial Press Edition 106).

I'm having trouble tracing its etymology.  Anyone have any insight into its origins?

Comment: This should give away the idea: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lie+through+one's+teeth Let me know.

Comment: It's not the idiom itself, but a clever phrasing that alludes to the well-known idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  So what happened, probably, is that the idiom "lie through one's teeth" fused with the word, "gap-toothed."  Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Can't speak to etymology but can tell you this expression is probably not associated with the phrase "lie through one's teeth."

Also, while someone who is gap-toothed has a lie gap, they do not mean the same thing.

Lie gap is an expression commonly used in Black American culture until circa 1980s/1990s. Older Black people still use it or, at least, know what it means if someone says it. Basically, anyone with a gap between the top 2 front teeth is considered to be a consummate liar. If you have a lie gap, your veracity is always suspect.

A Black woman's lie gap was considered by many men (especially Southern Black men) to be sexy.

While I don't know the origin, I do know what it means and what James Baldwin meant in his use of it.

Comment: Please provide proof for this lie gap and Black American culture.

Answer (score 1):

A gap-toothed woman being sexy, or promiscuous, can be traced to Chaucer.
Consider the Wife of Bath.
https://chaucer.fas.harvard.edu/pages/general-prologue-0

> 468         Gat-tothed was she, soothly for to seye.
>
> She had teeth widely set apart, truly to say.

In the Baldwin passage, we look
through the eyes of Gabriel,
a  prudish, sexually promiscuous preacher-to-be.
He sees himself  as called by God, whereas the women after whom he lusts,
with whom he dallies,
and at least one of whom he impregnates and abandons,
he considers "harlots."
He notices "the lie-gap" between the teeth of a woman
in a blues club or a bar.
He regards her as a threat because he's attracted to her.

The Baldwin passage also appears on page 90 of
Early Novels and Stories, 1988 Library of America.

Comment: I'll have to remember this one.

Comment: I have scanned the online Oxford English Dictionary entries for "gap" and "lie," and do not find this phrase. I think they need to update.